# How can I fix NGINX proxy_pass to route to my app on port 3000?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxypass

I am having issues with proxy_pass. A request comes in. It is routed to the port (3000) where my app is running, but always returns 404. If I make a request to the back end api urls, those return 200. So for example:
www.mysite.com/api   --- returns 200
BUT:
www.mysite.com/#/about  --- returns 404 
www.mysite.com/ or www.mysite.com ---returns 404

How can I have nginx serve the app that is running on port 3000?

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;


        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;



#       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
#       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

          gzip_vary on;
          gzip_proxied any;
          gzip_comp_level 6;
          gzip_buffers 16 8k;
          gzip_http_version 1.1;
          gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascrip$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}

#HTTPS
server{
listen 443;
ssl on;
server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
include snippets/ssl-mysite.com.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


location / {
     expires max;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;

}


}
```

For some reason I just cannot get the app to serve the public directory...

Hopefully the above config files will show what I have gotten wrong. I really appreciate your help. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Also..logs show the 404, but nothing else

Comment: What are the apps log showing (listening on port 3000)

Comment: just "running..." and port 3000

Comment: ...If I remove the proxy pass and just serve the root dir of my app, the static pages show up, but then the back end urls do not work.

Comment: In the app that is running on port 3000, there should be logs about how nginx is connecting. What are the those logs?

Comment: I am looking for those logs, but I do not know where they are.

Answer (score 0):

Try `proxy_pass` on your calls with the `/api/` endpoint

```
location /api/ {
     ...
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
     ...

}
```